# how to adjust mobile robot orientation If an obstacle is detected within the minimum safety distance?

Tags: mobile-robot, matlab, orientation

I do have calculated a trajectory for holonomic and omnidirectional mobile robot and make the robot follow the pre-defined trajectory making use of the resolved-velocity control. However, in some trails the robot is so close to the obstacles others it across the corner of the obstacles due to the fact that the post-smoothing algorithm utilized not checking the collision of the post-smoothing trajectory.

What I am trying to accomplish here is adjusting the robot orientation based on the minimum safety distance which is equal to the robot width. Therefore, how  to measure the distance putting in mind I am doin simulation? Secondly, after calculating the distances of the trajectory's waypoints (practically the robot centers) to obstacles surrounded how to re-orient the robot so that trajectory direction not changed only the robot platform orientation to be changed?